# How do I redirect a copy of all output of a shell script?

Tags: shell, pipe, stderr

I want to redirect a copy of all output of a shell script, there's some mount command and some echo in the script.

If I use `>> 2>&1`, I can't see the output from the command line.
If I use `| tee -a the_log_file 2>&1`, I can get all output in command line, but in the_log_file, there's no mount error output such as `mount.nfs: /mnt/folder is busy or already mounted` which I also want in `the_log_file`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use
`command 2>&1 | tee -a the_log_file`
instead of
`command | tee -a the_log_file 2>&1`

(If you ask me, it's pretty unintuitive that you need to not put the `2>&1` in an unintuitive place in the pipe case! ;) )

For the details, take a look at the **Illustrated Redirection Tutorial** in **Bash Hackers Wiki**. The illustration in section **Duplicating File Descriptor 2>&1** shows our case:

```
  ls /tmp/ doesnotexist 2>&1     |                   less

 ---       +--------------+              ---       +--------------+
( 0 ) ---->| /dev/pts/5   |     ------> ( 0 ) ---->|from the pipe |
 ---       +--------------+    /   --->  ---       +--------------+
                              /   /
 ---       +--------------+  /   /       ---       +--------------+
( 1 ) ---->| to the pipe  | /   /       ( 1 ) ---->|  /dev/pts    |
 ---       +--------------+    /         ---       +--------------+
                              /
 ---       +--------------+  /           ---       +--------------+
( 2 ) ---->|  to the pipe | /           ( 2 ) ---->| /dev/pts/    |
 ---       +--------------+              ---       +--------------+
```

Comment: If you want the error output of `command`, you have to redirect its error output, not the error output of `tee`.  Similarly, you redirect (with a pipe `|`) the standard output of the `command`, not the standard output of `tee`.  When you specify what you want, it becomes obvious why you do the redirection where you do it.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. The picture is wonderful. I'm kind of new to shell script and often come across different kinds of problems, such as `-eq` should be ` == `or` = `, how to write while a and b, int var increase or something, I find that different shell may have different solutions, so would you please suggest a book to read and totally depend on while using shell scripts?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your advice, it is really of great help.

Comment: @Blangero Oh, that's not because you are new to shell scripting - it's because the shell syntax is hard to understand, in part because it's inconsistent in many ways. But you can be sure that almost every flaw a shell has is based on a technical reason, often related to compability.

Comment: @Blangero  But your question about learning shell is very interesting in a way - maybe post it if you find a way that fits the site scope? The answer would best explain what you should stop to expect, and what to expect instead - giving a high level orientation... for example, it would explain why it does not make sense to expect a book to exist to "totally depend on".